# What is meaning of multiply a table to self and get one field?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-membership, webmatrix

This is the Source code of  **WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.GetHashedPassword**:

```
   private string GetHashedPassword(IDatabase db, int userId)
           {
               var pwdQuery = db.Query(@"SELECT m.[Password] " +
                                       @"FROM " + MembershipTableName + " m, " + SafeUserTableName + " u " +
                                       @"WHERE m.UserId = " + userId + " AND m.UserId = u." + SafeUserIdColumn).ToList();
               // REVIEW: Should get exactly one match, should we throw if we get > 1?
               if (pwdQuery.Count != 1)
               {
                   return null;
               }
               return pwdQuery[0].Password;
           }
```

You can find it on http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs

and by .net reflector check WebMatrix.WebData.dll

If you check code, you can see a User table multiply self and get Password field by running query, in simple way its like this:

```
SELECT m.Password FROM [Users] m, [Users] u
 WHERE m.[UserID] = 1 AND m.UserID = u.UserID
```

Comment: Funny, i think programmer of this function was noob :P!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the difference between `MembershipTableName` and `SafeUserTableName`:

```
internal static string MembershipTableName
{
    get { return "webpages_Membership"; }
}

private string SafeUserTableName
{
    get { return "[" + UserTableName + "]"; }
}

// represents the User table for the app
public string UserTableName { get; set; }
```

So the `SafeUserTableName` is really just `[UserTableName]` which can be set separately whereas `MembershipTableName` is *always* "webpages_Membership". So the query really resolves as (assuming `UserTableName` is set to "Users", `userId` is "1"):

```
SELECT m.[Password]
FROM webpages_Membership m, [Users] u
WHERE m.UserId = 1 AND m.UserId = u.[UserID]
```

I think the data is really separated between two different tables and this helps ensure that it's getting the correct values for all corner cases. Specifically, I suppose it helps ensure it does not retrieve a hashed password from `webpages_Membership` for a user who no longer exists in [`Users`] (though I would expect both entries to be wiped if a user is removed from the system, but perhaps it's just a double-check to avoid malicious use)

EDIT: Perhaps it's also to allow multiple "Users" tables to be used and share the same membership for one/many applications. So different "Users" tables generally might keep different information for different applications, but the "webpages_Membership" maintains a global set of users/passwords across *all* applications. When a MembershipProvider is setup for a *specific* application, this prevents access to the hashed password for a user who doesn't belong to a *different* application.

That is, a user belongs to ApplicationA, and ApplicationB, but not ApplicationC. Each application has its own "Users" table. The membership provider in ApplicationA/ApplicationB can access the hashed password for the user, but ApplicationC's membership provider cannot. But later on, the user may "link" their account with ApplicationC at which point an entry is added to the ApplicationC.Users table and the `GetHashedPassword` returns a valid result.